Inner Accordion Closes When Outer Accordion is Toggled in Angular with PrimeNG
I am working with Angular and PrimeNG and have a nested accordion, with one accordion inside another. The issue is that when I open the inner accordion and leave it open, and then open and close the outer accordion, the inner accordion closes very quickly, almost like a "flash," and does not stay open. I have set the outer accordion to start with the first tab open (`[activeIndex]="0"`), and the inner accordion also has an active tab. However, when I click on the outer accordion and close it, then open it again, the inner accordion closes again. How can I prevent this behavior and keep the inner accordion open when the outer accordion is opened again? Here is my code:
<p-accordion [activeIndex]="0">
  <p-accordionTab header="Header I">
    <div>
      <p-accordion [activeIndex]="0">
        <p-accordionTab header="Header I">
          <p>111</p>
          <p-accordion [activeIndex]="0">
            <p-accordionTab header="Header I">
              <p>222</p>
            </p-accordionTab>
          </p-accordion>
        </p-accordionTab>
      </p-accordion>
    </div>
  </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>


Try to handle the state based on the last activity, so you can reopen the accordion.
Use the onOpen event to manage the activeIndexChange and handle the last active state.

I tried to use ONOPEN and it didn't help even that I set them up through Service

check this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ha4zsq
